# Hide individual row if array is empty for that row

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am creating a statistics page that displays the number of times an item is used.

Each row has an `itemTitle` and `itemCount`.
Not every itemTitle have data (if user does not populate that data, but every row will have itemCount).

I want to hide the empty rows.

Here is what I am trying, but when this is true it hides all rows, not just the individual empty rows.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatsCell", for: indexPath)

    let itemTitle: UILabel      = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
    let itemCount: UILabel      = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel

    itemTitle.text              = self.statsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].itemTitle
    itemCount.text              = "\(self.statsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].itemCount)"

    if (self.statsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].itemTitle).isEmpty {

        tableView.rowHeight = 0

    }

    return cell
}
```

See the attached example

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` in your code and return the height as 0 for the row which has an empty array in the datasource. Return the normal height otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Yogi.  Note that your code is not swift 3.  Please modify to: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat So that future users will benefit